# FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to turn off persistence for an activity but I am getting the message above. Here is how I am configuring the settings in onCreate():

```
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(false).build();
        mFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Where do I call this if not right after?

Comment: Are you saying you only want to disable persistence it for a particular activity, but not for the entire app?

Comment: I only need it for one activity. I'm indifferent for the rest. Is my assumption below correct?

Comment: Yeah, you can't toggle it on or off after you use the APIs for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to set the settings in your very first activity when your app opens and have them persist throughout.

Comment: Any ideas on how to inline check this for an app that can follow less linear UI flows? (For instance a deeplink that opens C and then user backs up from C->B->A, but A wasn't initially launched and that is where the settings are? Filtering all opens through a Splash/Activity_0 which sets the Firestore settings is not as efficient as a simple inline check that prevents an app crash.)