# Service Firestore not available Nuxt2 Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

While deploying the SSR Nuxt 2 to firebase with functions and hosting it throws the following error in the image
[image: Debug Error in Webapp]

Firebase.js code

```
// import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
require("firebase/compat/firestore");
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

var fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
export { fb,db };
```

Comment: Probably a version upgrade to do or some different syntax. What is your current version?

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned by @kissu, the issue seems to be with the firebase version.

Try upgrading to the latest `firebase` version. Since lower versions of `Firebase` doesn't have the updated **compat libraries**.

And Sometimes Package managers have some issues while updating the libraries to the latest version. You can resolve these issues by reinstalling `firebase` or deleting and adding `node_modules` and `package.json`.

Also check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71579831/18265570)